# Quick Look audio distorted

Tags: itunes, audio, mp3, quicklook

When I play a song in Quick Look it sounds oversaturated and distorted. If I open it, it sounds great. What can be happening?

I noticed it with Mp3 at 320 kbps. With WAV and AAC it does not happens. I use a MacBook Air from mid 2011 with OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: all songs? what operating system on what device

Comment: any particular type? mp3, aac, wav, flac? or bit rate/sample rate?

Comment: I expander my question. I have discovered that only happens with some files, and I am trying to know what they have in common. Thanks!